# NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory.<init>() in Social Spring

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I am Trying to Configure Spring-Social into the XML file into my spring framework but i am getting this exception. and i am getting NoSuchmethod error while i have loaded all the class and i am trying to configure it to the xml so i can prevent this errors so please can anybody give me suggestion for the same.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactoryRegistry' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/BookServletmvc-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory.<init>()


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 50 more


java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
```

my configuration file is.

```
    <bean id="connectionFactoryRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
        <property name="connectionFactories">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.social.web.connect.ConnectController"> 
        <constructor-arg value="${application.url}" /> </bean> -->

    <bean id="userConnectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="jdbcConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg
            value="#{request.getRequestURI().split('/').length > 3 ? request.getRequestURI().split('/')[3] : 'guest'}" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />

    <bean id="jdbcConnectionRepository"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="userConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />     
    </bean>




    <bean id="connectController"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController"
        autowire="constructor">
        <property name="connectInterceptors">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and jars are

```
spring-social-security-1.1.0.M2.jar
spring-social-facebook-web-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-facebook-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-config-1.1.0.M4.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: You are using different versions of Spring Social. Try using only `spring-social-facebook-1.1.0.RELEASE` and `spring-social-security-1.1.0-RELEASE` and let me know what happens

Comment: @geoand thank you for ans and can u share me link for that jar ?

Comment: Check out http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook/1.1.0.RELEASE and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-security/1.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: so i need to delete that both jar file and need to include this new ones?

Comment: The problem is that you are not using Maven or Gradle, which means that you also need to include their dependencies (shown in the links I provided). I would strongly suggest that you use a build tool that handled dependencies and not try to handle them on your own

Comment: how we can do that? and ya by the way i need to include that two jars na?

Comment: You will need the two jars as well as any other dependencies those have. I suggest taking a look at an introductory Maven or Gradle tutorial.

Comment: i am not using mavan i am using simple structure of the working in eclipse

Comment: It will definitely pay off if you switch to Maven or Gradle. It might be a little tough at the beginning, but it's certainly worth it!

Comment: ohh true its little but i solve it and i have include different jars can i tell u which are they so u can give me more info.

Comment: I don't know what the specific dependencies are for those jars. But the links I suggested mention them

Comment: okey @geoand i am just maintaining them okey just min